# Losing rows of data after converting with as.numeric

Tags: r

I have some data, with 8 columns and around 750 rows, read into R with:

```
    data <- read.csv(file.choose() , header=TRUE)
```

I have created a new dataframe to specify which columns I am using (I will be doing a factor analysis on the data):

```
    data.TT <- data[ , 16:23 ]
```

After this, and trying to apply simple arithmetic, I learn that the data is not numeric (it is all integer values). I, therefore, converted the columns to numeric using:

```
    data.TTn <- cbind( 
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Sociability)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Kamplystdrift)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Temperament)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Forsvarsdrift)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Skarphet)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Daadkraft)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Hardhet)),
            as.numeric(as.character(data.TT$Nervekonstitusjon))
    )
    data.TTn
```

However, I have lost some rows now. I only have around 550 rows versus 750.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this might be? Please let me know if you require more information.

Thanks!

Comment: If there are only integers in your data, R would most likely read the data correct (as numeric or integer data). Do you happen to have any special characters for missing values e.g. "NA" "#NA" or the like?

Comment: if you have to do `as.numeric(as.character(...))` then I'm guessing your columns were imported as factors and so they were "interpreted" as character by R so I agree with @beginneR, there must be some "weird" data inside. It may be due to a problem of decimal separator. Is your decimal separator a "." in you csv file ?

Comment: I did replace values that were entered as "." in the original data with NA. Then used na.omit to have a dataframe with just complete cases.

Comment: that's probably where you've lost some rows...

Comment: And those NA entries you made, are they with or without quotes (NA vs "NA" or 'NA')?

Comment: @user3237820  You dont have to use `as.numeric(as.character(` individually, you can do `data.TT[, 16:23] <- lapply(data.TT[,16:23, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: @akrun Better advice would be to fix data import. Looks like they should use `data <- read.csv(file.choose() , header=TRUE, na.strings = ".")`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The missing rows only appeared after changing the values to as.numeric (thanks for the code @akrun). They were present after replacing/removing the values…Or does that not matter?

Comment: Fixing the import worked! Thanks for all your quick help. Much appreciated :)